# How to write the symbol gamma in greek leeter in the csv file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, symbols, gamma

I want to plot in the csv file the symbol gamma in greek letter. I tried Unicode and the CSS code but I got errors or not the desired result.

For instance, the CSS-code for gamma is the following one:\03B3

```
Home=[['home','\03B3 ']]

if glass_type!=3:
    with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:       

    thewriter.writerows(Home)
```

The expected result is the symbol Gamma in Greek letter; but, I get the following result: B3

Consider that the CSS code works for the degree symbol with the following code: \xb0

Comment: Sorry, you can delete  if glass_type!=3:

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: I guess is Python 3. Moreover, I am using Spyder 3.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the unicode CSS code wrong:

```
Home=[['home','\u03B3 ']] # note the \u
```

printing `Home` results in:

```
[['home', 'γ']]
```

Note, however, that since python 3's default strings are unicode, you could just use the gamma symbol in your script (this improves readability a lot too, btw):

```
Home = [['home', 'γ']]
```

Comment: Do I have to import something?

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b3' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Put the full error output (including the line and trace) in your question. Also, add the output of running `python --version` in a terminal window

Comment: File "C:\Users\BE110924\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/BE110924/Desktop/Fd_/INPUT_OUTPUT_fd.py", line 364, in <module> thewriter.writerows(Line_1)
File"C:\Users\BE110924\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b3' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I am using Anaconda 3

Comment: What version of python are you using **exactly**? This is important, because versions prior to python 3.6 require you to install the package `win-unicode-console` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32176732/3214872) for more details). You can get python's versions importing `sys` and printing `sys.version`, or by running in a console `python --version`

Comment: Actually, does `print('\u03B3')` raise any error? Or is the error coming from inside `writerows` (in which case I can't help you further without seeing the implementation of `writerows`)?

Comment: Hi, you are right. It works fine.The implementation in writerows are attached above

Comment: Hi I found, I just have to add   encoding='utf-8-sig'  in this line   with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvFile: